# What is the definition of "program" according to C#?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, language-lawyer, specifications

According to the [C# spec 5.0 (sec 1.2)](https://books.google.com/books?id=btlM21ivisMC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22The%20key%20organizational%20concepts%20in%20C%23%20are%20programs,%20namespaces,%20types,%20members%22&source=bl&ots=2LWaquCbz3&sig=Na7zR_m9iQ_Yz5UYTaKRNXxDc-8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RiCPVNynL4K2yASmioHIDA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20key%20organizational%20concepts%20in%20C%23%20are%20programs%2C%20namespaces%2C%20types%2C%20members%22&f=false)

> The key organizational concepts in C# are programs, namespaces, types, members, and assemblies. C# programs consist of one or more source files. Programs declare types, which contain members and can be organized into namespaces. Classes and interfaces are examples of types. Fields, methods, properties, and events are examples of members. When C# programs are compiled, they are physically packaged into assemblies. Assemblies typically have the file extension .exe or .dll, depending on whether they implement applications or libraries.

But they never explain what a program is! Is a program the set of all source files that are used to create a single assembly? Or might a program be made up of several assemblies?

It matters because later the "program" is used to define other concepts, such as internal accessibility.

**To Clarify:** I'm asking, *within the context of the C# 5.0 Specification*, what is a "program"?

Comment: Reads pretty clear to me.

Comment: Can't really get a much better definition than the one posted. It's pretty clear there can be multiple assemblies from the types, that are usually exes and dlls.

Comment: See section 3.5.2 says "If the declared accessibility of T is internal, the accessibility domain of T is the program text of P." and it says "the program text of a program is defined as all program text contained in all source files of the program", which is a circular definition! But I guess a program must be a single assembly or else internal would be the same as public. Right?

Comment: See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx changes the definition of internal to be based on assembly, not program. I guess Microsoft realized the concept of program was too confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either or.  Based on the above definition, a program is a concept rather than a physically defined boundary.  As such, it could be a single dll or a large collection of assemblies.

Comment: If it could be either then the notion of accessibility domains is not well-defined. `internal` accessibility is defined as accessible within the program text of a program P, but of course we know that means within a single assembly (unless you are using `IntervalsVisibleToAttribute`). It is pretty obvious from the usage that compiler considers the program to be the set of all input source files.

Comment: I understand exactly where you're coming from.  To clarify, I mean either/or as in a program could theoretically be composed of a single assembly or multiple assemblies.  In terms of multiple assemblies, I agree, absolutely the compiler has to regard all input source files and then determine the intern accessibility of each source file as it relates to the members of the source files, the assembly itself, and other potential assemblies within the program.  I think your excellent clarification only further enhances my original point, either/or :).

Comment: @JohnHenckel I guess take a step back and think about what a compiler implementer is required to do by the spec. The spec does not mention `InternalsVisileToAttribute` so it is an implementation specific behavior. The implementer is required to have accessibility modifiers work the way they defined in section 3.5.2, and a program is a collection of "one or more source files". Whether the program is packaged into a single or multiple physical assemblies also seems like an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a **program** is a set of instructions that could be executed in a computer to perform a specific task. It could be a collection of assemblies or a single assembly to perform a task. It doesn't necessarily be a complete solution. I.e. it's not an application. Some may argue that they are same. But, there's a difference. They are not synonyms.

To understand what a **program** is you should understand the difference between a **program** and an **application**. There's a distinction between an **application** and a **program**.

> A computer **program**, or just a program, is a sequence of instructions,
>   written to perform a specified task with a computer. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program)

On the other hand, an application is a set of programs working together to solve a complex problem.

> **Application** software is a set of one or more programs designed to carry out operations for a specific application. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)

E.g. To solve a specific business problem you might need an application, which internally performs multiple tasks to solve that problem.

Comment: I don't think such a broad definition of "program" is useful here. According to that definition, a single function is a program.

Answer (score 0):

John, I think the whole confusion is due to historical and terminological inconsistencies. In the beginning of computer era, only programs existed. Everybody understood a computer program as ANY SET OF INSTRUCTION for computer with defined functionality. It did not matter whether it was written on a paper, punched on punchcards, or recorded on a tape. Then new generations of software developers, languages, frameworks, etc. produced new terms, some of which had the same meaning, but carried different names. I can point to the similar story with "function" (C, C++) vs "method" (C#). In general, there is no point in answering to your question - it will not produce any practical results.

Comment: The C# specification defines a language, so it should *not* be ambiguous. The definition of "internal" accessibility depends on the definition of "program". Assuming that Microsoft Visual Studio is a correct implementation, a "program" is the set of source files that are compiled into a **single assembly** (exe or dll). However, I think @mike z has a good point: how the compiler packages the output is *not* defined by the language. For instance, the compiler *could* put every class into a separate .clz file, or there might not even be a compiler... so "program" *is inherently ambiguous*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. Apologies, if my question was unclear. I meant to ask:  *Within the context of the C# 5.0 Specification*, what is a "**program**"? Rereading [section 3.5.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691128%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) carefully, now I think it is clear that a "program" is intended to mean the set of source files that are used to create a **single** assembly (exe or dll). I do not think the specification is ambiguous. Throughout the entire specification "program" always has this definition. But it is unfortunately never actually defined. Probably it will be improved in C# 6.0.